# Error while building DSENT to model power & area of NoC

Tags: gem5

I'm tring to use DSENT in `/ext/dsent` directory to model power and area of my designed NoC, I have called `cmake` and it executed all right, but next I followed the guidance of README which says

```
===============================================================================
Build (installation)
===============================================================================
To build DSENT:
    % make
```

So I called `make` command but encountered below error:

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target dsent
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dsent.dir/DSENT.cc.o
c++: warning: /bin/sh:: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: error: /bin/sh:: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
c++: warning: 1:: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: error: 1:: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
c++: warning: python-config:: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: error: python-config:: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
c++: warning: not: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: error: not: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
c++: warning: found: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: error: found: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dsent.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/dsent.dir/DSENT.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/dsent.dir/DSENT.cc.o'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/dsent.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I have checked my system requirements and they satisfy in README, could you help me how to solve this problem?

It's the original CMakeLists.txt:

```
make_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (DSENT)
# find out all the file that need to be compiled
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS  "*.h" "*.cc")

# add the library
add_library(dsent MODULE ${SRCS})

SET(PYTHON_CONFIG "python-config")

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" "`${PYTHON_CONFIG} --includes`")
EXEC_PROGRAM(${PYTHON_CONFIG} ARGS --cflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_CFLAGS)
EXEC_PROGRAM(${PYTHON_CONFIG} ARGS --ldflags OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_LFLAGS)

set_target_properties(dsent PROPERTIES
        PREFIX ""
        COMPILE_FLAGS "${PYTHON_CFLAGS} -std=c++11 "
        LINK_FLAGS "${PYTHON_LFLAGS}")
```